# Conveying the idea of " judge a book by its cover" by " juger un livre par sa couverture"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais

What are some colloquial ways to convey the idea of

> "You can’t judge a book by its cover"

meaning one should not judge something or someone by how it, he or she looks - it's what's on the inside or the content that matters most.

So for

> But you must never judge a book by its cover!

I would say

> Mais (il ne) faut jamais juger un livre par sa couverture !

[Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/you+can%27t+judge+a+book+by+its+cover.html) affirme that the expression française correspond à l'expression anglaise. But that majority of sources are canadiennes. Also, I think that judge in English is more frequently used that the verb juger in French. Lastly, I don't 
recall hearing a native to use this expression.

Comment: Linguee n'affirme **pas**, il propose des traductions qui proviennent de corpus publiés mais les traductions restent sous la responsabilité de celui qui fait la traduction, il y en a des bonnes, il y en a des meilleures et il y en des complètement mauvaises. Enfin dans ce cas c'est pas faux, c'est un anglicisme et il y a mieux.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Il ne faut pas se fier aux apparences.

Answer (score 11):

La traduction proposée est bonne, néanmoins avec un sens fort similaire (bien qu'il y ai une légère différence) on peut aussi dire:

> - L'habit ne fait pas le moine

Comment: 1- La traduction proposée par Dimitris n'est pas bonne, c'est vraiment un anglicisme, en français plus standard on dit *On ne juge pas un livre **à** sa couverture* 2-  L'habit ne fait pas le moine (en anglais: [clothes don't make the man](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/clothes+don%27t+make+the+man)) ne s'emploie pas pour des situations, alors que l'équivalent de *you mustn't judge a book by its cover*:  « Il ne faut pas se fier aux apparences » peut s'appliquer à des situations.

Comment: Bon point pour le *à*, ça ne m'avait pas choqué à la première lecture.

Answer (score 6):

Je pense que « juger un livre **à** sa couverture » est grammaticalement plus correct.

Answer (score 1):

Les apparences sont souvent trompeuses.

Answer (score 0):

On peut dire aussi “juger quelqu'un sur sa bonne mine”.

Comment: Parce que pour un être humain, on ne parlera pas de *juger un livre à sa couverture*, mais bien de *juger quelqu'un sur sa bonne mine*. Tout dépend du contexte, en fait :^)

Comment: and the initial question says (I quote): “meaning one should not judge something or ***someone*** by how it, he or she looks”. In French, nobody will compare a human being to a book, which would be very disrespectful :^(